# javascript find div id inside string and delete it's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, find

I have a string with some **variable html** saved inside, among which a div with static id="time",

example:

`myString = "<div class="class">blahblah</div><div id="time">1:44</div>"`

How can I create a new identical string cutting off only the time? (1:44 in this case).
I can't look for numbers or the ":" because is not safe in my situation.

What i've tried without success is this:

```
  var content = divContainer.innerHTML;

  var jHtmlObject = jQuery(content);
  var editor = jQuery("<p>").append(jHtmlObject);
  var myDiv = editor.find("#time");
  myDiv.html() = '';
  content = editor.html();
  console.log('content -> '+content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myString = '<div class="class">blahblah</div><div id="time">1:44</div>';

//create a dummy span
//put the html in it
//find the time
//remove it's inner html
//execute end() so the jQuery object selected returns to the span
//console log the innerHTML of the span
console.log($('<span>').html(myString).find('#time').html('').end().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a regular expression in plain javascript like so:

```
myString.replace(/(<div id="time">).*(<\/div>)/, '$1$2')
```

If you want to extract only the 1:44 portion you can use the following:

```
myString.match(/(<div id="time">)(.*)(<\/div>)/)[2]
```